# Programming a front-end for a MySQL database

Tags: .net, mysql

I need to make a front-end desktop application for a MySQL database to be used on a Windows machine. What language(s) should I use to make a front end that will connect to the MySQL backend?

I will need to be able to search through the database and pull data.

Comment: What's wrong with [the existing frontends](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3880961/Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools.htm)?

Comment: What are you most comfortable developing in? There's MySQL connectors for a variety of languages. See: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: I think the OP means a desktop application that uses MySQL as a data store, not a gui management tool for the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has connectors for ADO.NET (and lots of other languages and frameworks). See 
[MySQL Connectors](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

You tagged your question with .NET -- you can use any .NET language, principal among them being VB.NET and C#.

Comment: hey jay thanks for your answer, it doesnt need to be NET could be anything

Comment: There are a few common technology "stacks" that group platform components. MySQL is most commonly associated with LAMP: Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP, where you'll program in PHP. That doesn't preclude other arrangements, like the unfortunately named WIMP: Windows + IIS + MySQL + PHP. Still, MySQL is very often paired with PHP. See this poll to give a further idea: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/quickpolls/index.php?pollname=primary-prog-lang

Answer (score 0):

Create, edit, delete, search, update.

I like drag and drop, so for rapid programming, i myself would use these tools:
Visual Studio.NET for pure windows,
JDeveloper for linux/unix/etc.